# Matlab not writing to file

Tags: matlab, csv

I am working on the following code. This code is used to write downloaded data from a database to a .csv file. The issue here is that the code formats and writes data in a specific manner to the .csv file which is further used in subsequent codes. Hence I cannot use alternative ways of dumping the data to a .csv file. I am stuck with the following code where I can only make small alterations to make it work. The entire code is as follows:

```
fid = fopen(IFile,'wt');
fprintf(fid,'ID,Date');

fprintf(fid,',DATE');

%// ERROR HERE:
for jj=1:length(tVars)
    fprintf(fid,',%s',tVars{jj});
end
%// end ERROR

fprintf(fid,'\n');

for ii=1:length(id)

    %// Another ERROR here
    for jj=2:length(tVars)
        s = ['tmpVar = ' tVars{jj} '{ii};'];
        eval(s); %// end second ERROR

        tmpVar(strfind(tmpVar, ',')) = ';';
        if strcmp('NA',tmpVar) || strcmp('NaN',tmpVar) || ...
                strcmp('N/A',tmpVar)
            fprintf(fid,',');
        else
            fprintf(fid,',%s',tmpVar);
        end
        clear tmpVar
    end   
    fprintf(fid,'\n');
    clear tmp*
end
fclose(fid);
toc(tStart);
```

I get mainly two errors in the above code each corresponding to the marked parts of the code. For the first  part, the error is

> Error using `fprintf`....
>   Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs

The second error corresponding to the second part is

> Undefined function or method `'eval'` for input arguments of type 'cell'

I tried correcting the above errors:
    1) first error by using

```
for jj=1:length(tVars)
    fprintf(fid,',%s,',char(tVars{jj}));
end
```

and 2) second error by using

```
for jj=2:length(timeVars)
       s = ['tmpVar = ' char(timeVars{jj}) '{ii};'];
       eval(s);
```

But when I make the above alterations, although I do not get any errors and code runs smoothly, I get an empty .csv file with no data/headings written to it. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[`eval` is evil!](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)**

Comment: have you tried using debugger and see what's going on?

Comment: yes but debugging did not help. The code did run smoothly after using debugger. But the file was empty.

Comment: I would suggest putting a breakpoint at `fprintf(fid,',%s',tVars{jj})` and inspecting the contents of `tVars{jj}`.  I suspect that rather than containing a string as expected, it actually contains a cell array of something.

Comment: @Veronica the point of debugger is not to see the code "swooshing by" but rather inspect what exactly is going on...

Comment: Yeah.... closing.   BTW, @Shai - I laughed at your comment.  Thank you for my laugh of the day.

Comment: @rayryeng keep laughing... have a lovely day